# Block javascript disabled users from wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, noscript

I am having a huge problem. I need to prevent access to non javascript users for a page on my website. I am not very technical when it comes to websites, hmtl or java ect. But I have a page that i would like non javascript users to not be able to access. I have tried lots of code from here in my header and footer such as 
`<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=nojs/index.php">
</noscript>`

but it does not work. 
To put this into more detail my problem is that a host a webpage with a list of download links. There is an app (web browser) for amazon devices (android) that accesses webpages and allows you to download but it comes with javascript disabled by default.
This means that my Ads dont show and i am now getting 40TB a month bandwidth usage from people using this software which means i may have to pull the site soon as it costs more to run than the ads give back.

I think i need to either block non javascript users. Or is there a way i can make my links on that page in javascript so that none javascript users cant see or use them?

In an ideal world i would just like to display a message saying please enable javascript in settings but i have tried many header codes with no success. Any help here greatly appreciated

Comment: noscript tag...

Comment: I'm really not good with this and unsure how to do it ? Tried the no script in my post and it did nothing